# How to tar folders with specific letter

Tags: linux, tar, wget

I have a long list of folders. i want `tar` only folder which starts with "a". How can i do that?

Actually, I am having photo gallery website, which has 1000s of folders. I wish to move another server using `wget` option. Total size of the gallery is around 25GB. Moving 25GB will take more time, for that i am looking for the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are all folders within the same top folder? If so, the answer is simple:

```
tar cf /path/to/outfile.tar /path/to/folders/a*
```

If the files are not all in the same folder, you can do a find to get them:

```
find /path/to/folders/ -type d -name a\* -exec tar rf /path/to/outfile.tar {} \;
```

Comment: Jenny D: Yes, All of them are same folder.

Comment: And I will add my vote to the rsync suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mask for inclusion. Like `a*`

To move\sync files and folders take a look over `rsync`

Answer (score 1):

```
tar cvf <tarfile> a*
```

from the directory containing all the folders will do what you want.

Comment: +1 for rsync, since if the connection fails, it will resume the transfer and copy only remaining files; if you don't have access to setup a rsync daemon at the other end, just use rsync over ssh